# Android My Sites edit screen rendering incorrectly

Tags: bug, android-app, user-interface, rendering

It appears that the edit my sites screen has some problems. I am able to add and remove sites, but I can't move them up or down, and only one is visible at a time.

[image]
[image]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: MotoG3

  - OS Version: 6.0 (28)